# Can a bent hub damage my fork?

Tags: wheels, hub, fork

I've recently noticed that my front hub is bent, or at least the parts that connect to the fork (any name for this?). It's not a huge bent, but it's clearly visible with your eyes.

It fits the fork without any problem, but I'm wondering if I should keep these, or if that may damage my fork somehow (as a fork is probably more expensive than hubs...)

See the highlighted part in the picture? That's the bent part. It seems to be bent through the whole length of the hub, not only the external part. Actually, when I rotate the wheel, I can see this part moving from side to side.

[image: Illustration of the damaged part]

Comment: Are you referring to the axle?

Comment: Probably yes :-)

Comment: Can you post a picture?

Comment: If the axle is bent, the fork would only be my second concern, right after my teeth. Bent axles might have (miniature) cracks that might lead to catastrophic failure, i.e. biting the handlebar. Axles are quite cheap and easily replaced on most hubs, so why risk it?

Comment: Didn't know about this, but I will therefore change this ASAP. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Btw, I just added an image of the bent part. Is this the so-called "axle"?

Comment: Yes, that's an axle.

Comment: If the axle is visibly bent the bearings will go bad very quickly.  (The danger to the fork is minor compared to other hazards here.)  The axle (and possibly the entire hub) should be replaced.  (How did you manage to bend this?)

Comment: I suspect it happened years ago, when I was jumping with the bike. Maybe the wheel nuts weren't tight enough and the hub moved within the fork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part you've circled is called the axle, even if it is not solid, and if it's bent you need to replace the axle, or the hub, or the whole wheel, whatever is cheapest. It can likely cause minor damage to your fork, but more importantly, if it's bent then it can fail- potentially in a catastrophic manner. Get it fixed, cheap insurance.